# ETABS 2015 OAPI and Python - TypeError - CreateObject takes exactly 2 arguments ( 1 given)

Tags: python, api

I am trying to work with ETABS2015 API. As a first step I am replicating one of the examples from the ETABS API help. The example is in VB .NET.

The example first creates an API class object by pointing to the program .exe location.
This is implemented in VB .NET using

```
Set ETABSObject = myHelper.CreateObject("Path\To\EXE")
```

CreateObject being a method of class Helper in ETABS2015.

I am trying the following in Python to achieve the equivalent.

```
import clr
import math
import System
import sys
sys.path
sys.path.append("C:\\Program Files\\Computers and Structures\\ETABS 2015\\")
clr.AddReferenceToFile("ETABS2015.dll")
import ETABS2015
path = 'C:\\Program Files\\Computers and Structures\\ETABS 2015\\ETABS.exe'
eObj = ETABS2015.Helper.CreateObject(path)
```

Running the script gives me the TypeError: CreateObject() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given). I am not sure how to correct this. Any suggestions?

I did notice a number of questions with similar error, but most their resolution requires modification of the method function. But in this case I am unable to access the method as it is being read from the dll.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try separate `eObj = ETABS2015.Helper.CreateObject(path)` into two steps

Here is my example:

```
import System 
import clr
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath(r"C:\Program Files\Computers and Structures\ETABS 2016\ETABS2016.dll")
from ETABS2016 import *

path = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles), "Computers and Structures", "ETABS 2015", "ETABS.exe")
helper = Helper()
csiApp = helper.CreateObject(path)
csiApp.ApplicationStart()
Model=csiApp.SapModel
```